# Counting number of sub-graphs of a graph having an edge between each node pair

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a directed connected non-weighted graph as input.I want to print a result to the output where result is the number of sub-graphs in which there is an edge between each pair of nodes of the sub-graph (in either of the directions) . The sub-graphs having  zero nodes or a single node are also counted in the result.Since the result might be too large so result modulo 10^9 + 7 has to be printed.

The input-graph will not have multiple edges between any node pair and the edges are directed from node u to node v only if u < v .

### Sample input:

3 // no of nodes

2 // no of edges

1 2

2 3

### Sample output:

6

### Reason:

1.no nodes

2.node 1

3.node 2

4.node 3

5.node 1,2

6.node 2,3

I am a using a recurrence result = sum(DP[nodes])+1, where DP[node] = sum(DP[adjacentnodes])+1
But this is giving 7 to the output . Kindly suggest some better method for this graph having number of nodes <= 3000 .

Thanks

Comment: For a complete graph on 3000 nodes, there are 2^3000 cliques (a subgraph in which every pair of nodes is linked by an edge is called a clique).  It's impractical to try to count them all.  It makes more sense to try to count *maximal* cliques -- that is, cliques that can't be extended into larger cliques by adding more vertices.  There are still a large (exponential) number of these.

Comment: @j_random_hacker the result modulo 10^9+7 has to printed in this question . Sorry for mentioning this later . Also since an edge exists between (u,v) pair with u < v , the graph is not complete .

Comment: @heropanti are you aware still it could be complete? for instance for node 1,2,3 we have : 1->2, 1->3, 2->3

Comment: yah !! I mean the maximum edges = (number of node) choose 2 !!less than node*(node-1) !! By the way can't this question  have a polynomial time solution ?

Comment: It's effectively a complete undirected graph, since the criterion for being a valid subgraph doesn't care about edge direction, and for any pair of vertices u and v, either u < v or v < u, so there's potentially an *undirected* edge between them.

Comment: Just determining a maximum size clique is NP-complete, so I doubt you'll find a poly time algorithm for this.